# Angular alternative $http

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, angular-http

In AngularJS for sending a request I use the builtin $http service.

What shall I use for sending a request to a server in Angular? I can't find any doc that covers the subject.

Comment: You can still use $http. Is it not working?

Comment: I use AngularJS2 not 1.x. Do you have example how to use $http?

Comment: Are you using the alpha for Angular 2? If so it doesn't have an http service yet. They are working on designing it here: https://github.com/jeffbcross/http-design

Comment: Thank you. Yeah it is not implement yet.

Comment: You can use [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: There is an [api preview](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/Http-class.html) for the new http service on the Angular 2 [website](https://angular.io/) now

There is a basic [http service](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/angular2/src/http/http.ts) in Angular 2 currently, but its very minimalist right now. This software is in alpha and is very likely to change, so you may just want to use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), implement your own [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), or use a library like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead. Currently, the Angular 2 http api is essentially identical to the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Given that [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is far less likely to change, I suggest just using that.

If you want to use the Angular 2 service, [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2932377769ca9365339a1edeb3a4d94bab5b8083/modules/examples/src/http/http_comp.ts) is an example...

```
import {bootstrap, Component, View, NgFor, Inject} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Http, httpInjectables} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({selector: 'http-app'})
@View({
  directives: [NgFor],
  template: `
    <h1>people</h1>
    <ul class="people">
      <li *ng-for="#person of people">
        hello, {{person.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class HttpCmp {
  people: Object;
  constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get('./people.json').toRx().map(res => res.json()).subscribe(people => this.people = people);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work anymore? `map` is not a member of `EventEmitter`

Comment: Check the "Breaking Changes" section in the link I added in my edit. Basically, you just need to call .toRx() before calling .map now

Answer (score 3):

Simple http get sample:

```
http.get('./friends.json').map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(res => this.result = res);
```

I have a working sample here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http